# Find all the fridays (increment to next friday) in a interval of date

Tags: sql, date, sybase

For an x (@startDate) and y (@endDate) interval of date. I want to be able to increment on the next Friday until @endDate.

**Pseudo-code**
init currentDate to startDate

Loop until endDate

set currentDate to next Friday

end loop

**I tried this:**

```
set datefirst 5 /* Friday */
CASE
WHEN DATEPART(cdw, @currentDate) = @@datefirst THEN DATEADD(dd, 7, @currentDate)
ELSE DATEADD(dd, ( @@datefirst + ( DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) ) ) % 7, @currentDate)
END
```

It doesn't work...

Comment: Do you want to find Friday preceding the end date in the interval?

Comment: I don't need the friday after the endDate thats all. @HamletHakobyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATEADD(dd,(CASE DATEPART(cdw, @currentDate) WHEN 5 THEN 7 ELSE 5 - DATEPART(cdw,@currentDate) END),@currentDate)
```